# Create new dictionary out of two existing dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Consider two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a': 35, 'b': 39, 'c': 20}  # (with the values as integers)

dict2 = {'a': 23, 'c': 12}
```

I want to obtain the following:

```
dict_new = {'a': 0.657, 'c': 0.6}  # (with the values as floats, as values of dict2/dict1)
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What about `'b'`, and what about keys in `dict2` that aren't in `dict1`?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the common keys using `dict2.keys() & dict1`  and then just do the division:

```
dict1 = {'a':35, 'b': 39, 'c':20} #(with the values as integers)

dict2 = {'a':23, 'c':12}

d3 = {k: dict2[k] / dict1[k] for k in dict2.keys() & dict1}
```

If you want the values rounded to three decimal places use `round(dict2[k] / dict1[k],3)`, if the keys from dict2 should always be in dict1 then you can simply iterate over the items of dict2:

```
d = {k:v / dict1[k] for k,v in dict2.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic_new = {}
for key in dic2.keys():
    dic_new[key]=float(dict2[key])/dict1[key]
```